# Parse .deleteInBackground not working (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, swift3

I'm using Parse (parse.com) for the first time with Xcode and Swift 3.  When I try deleting an object here from the cloud, it doesn't update and I get the following message:

`[Error]: Object not found. (Code: 101, Version: 1.12.0)`

In other parts of my code, deleting objects has worked just fine, but in this instance it's not.  It's also strange because when I print the request from the query (below), I do get an object, the one I was looking for.  I've tried calling the delete method with a block and got the same "Object not found" error.  And I've ensured the class in the database has read & write permissions enabled, if that's any help.

This is my code:

```
let query = PFQuery(className: "FriendRequests")
query.whereKey("fromID", equalTo: self.incomingIDs[indexPath.row])
query.whereKey("toID", equalTo: PFUser.current()?.objectId)

query.getFirstObjectInBackground(block: { (object, error) in
    if error == nil {
        if let request = object {
            print(request) // This works!
            request.deleteInBackground()
        }
    }
})
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What's with `if let request`?   Also, use `request.deleteInBackground()` with the progress block to view the error object.

Comment: Additionally, this looks the perfect use-case for relational data.  Try adding a column called `friendRequests` rather than having a separate class.  This way you would call `PFUser.current().relation(forKey: "friendRequests")`.  You can then query that as you would a normal class.

Comment: @evan.stoddard I'll try that, seems like a much more elegant solution.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came back to this and figured out it was just a problem with the ACL, if anyone ever has a similar issue...

When the object was first created, only the user who made the request had write access.  Before saving the request object I set the write access to public.

```
let acl = PFACL()
acl.getPublicReadAccess = true
acl.getPublicWriteAccess = true
friendRequest.acl = acl
```